# Excel: Z-Order of Series in Chart and Legend

Tags: excel, charts, legend, z-order

I have a combo chart in excel, with clustered bar charts (for a box plot) and lines. I am trying to display the bar charts/box plot in front of the lines, but am able to do so.

I tried moving the bar charts to the top and/or bottom in "select data" - but no change.

Any suggestions?

Am using Excel 2013.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe it is not possible. You can change display ordering of Excel series by:

- changing the plot order of the series (this is what you have done in the "Select data" dialog),
- changing the axis on which the series are displayed (series on secondary axis are displayed over the series on the primary axis).

But from my experiments no combination of changes makes the lines appear behind the columns.

There are two workarounds that might or might not help you:

- you can create two charts on top of each other and put the chart with the lines behind the one with the columns,
- or you could create a line chart (most likely you would need scatter chart), that is not a single line but a series of segments where the columns are not shown (this one is not that easy to do)

Answer (score 0):

What are the lines for? If you are just trying to identify some zones along the value axis, you could instead use stacked areas, which would give a banded appearance. Areas are always drawn behind bars and columns, while lines are always drawn in front of lines and columns.